# How do you clear the notification center in Titanium for iOS?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have basic push notifications sending to my application. I was wondering if there was a way to clear the notifications in the notification center when the app is opened?

Comment: just verify this link, i think you'll get some information from there http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135054/clearing-notification-center-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There You may use `Ti.UI.iPhone.appBadge = 0;` to reset the appBagde in the device. From 3.x, Appcelerator has added a new functionality to reset the badge on Appcelerator server.

[Cloud.PushNotifications.setBadge()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-set_badge) method allows the user to set the badge and [Cloud.PushNotifications.resetBadge()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-reset_badge_put) will reset the badge in the notification center.

Comment: Yup, this actually solved it. I wish it was just documented better in TI.